# IRC bot only receiving 1/2 of messages

Tags: python, bots, irc

My IRC bot wont receive about half of chat commands entered. I am using the freenode server on a custom channel. Is there anyway I could improve this?

Pic:
[image]

```
import sys
import socket
import string

HOST="irc.freenode.net"
PORT=6667
NICK="FedoraCoinBot"
IDENT="CephonBot"
REALNAME="CephonBot"
CHAN="#cephbot"
readbuffer=""

s=socket.socket( )
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.send("NICK %s\r\n" % NICK)
s.send("USER %s %s bla :%s\r\n" % (IDENT, HOST, REALNAME))
s.send("JOIN :%s\r\n" % CHAN)
s.send("PRIVMSG %s :%s\r\n" % (CHAN, "Hi! I am a FedoraCoin Bot!"))
s.send("PRIVMSG %s :%s\r\n" % (CHAN, "Designed by Cephon ;)"))

# Loop
while 1:
 text=s.recv(2040)
 print text
 readbuffer=readbuffer+s.recv(1024)
 temp=string.split(readbuffer, "\n")
 readbuffer=temp.pop( )
 if text.find('!help') !=-1:
    s.send("PRIVMSG %s :%s\r\n" % (CHAN, "You said help"))

for line in temp:
    line=string.rstrip(line)
    line=string.split(line)

    # Let's make it so that we don't get kicked -.-
if(line[0]=="PING"):
    s.send("PONG %s\r\n" % line[1])
```

Answer (score 5):

Let’s go through some parts of the input handling:

```
text=s.recv(2040)
print text
```

So first of all, you receive some text and print that. That’s the only thing you see in your console output.

```
readbuffer=readbuffer+s.recv(1024)
```

Next, you read more text—which is later never printed. So it won’t appear in your console output, *but* it is the only text that is considered for actual command parsing (you never access `text` from above again).

```
temp=string.split(readbuffer, "\n")
```

You split it into lines—that’s okay. Be careful though that just because you received 1024 bytes, that doesn’t mean that the *very last* line is already a complete response from the server. It could be interrupted in between, so you should wait until you receive another line break for that one too (i.e. never handle the last line until you completed reading it).

```
readbuffer=temp.pop( )
```

You get the first line but assign it to `readbuffer` which I thought was the buffer containing all the left-over text? You should make it more clear what purpose your variables serve.

```
if text.find('!help') !=-1:
    s.send("PRIVMSG %s :%s\r\n" % (CHAN, "You said help"))
```

Here, you check `text` again. So only if `!help` happens to be in that initial 2040 bytes, it will be handled. Other commands in there will be ignored; and `!help` commands outside of that block will be ignored too. Furthermore, this will also (incorrectly) handle messages like *“To see what the bot can do, type !help”* etc.

```
for line in temp:
    line=string.rstrip(line)
    line=string.split(line)
```

You are iterating over the rest of the lines, and modify them. Afterwards you throw the changes away. Modifying `line` will *not* change the values within the `temp` list.

```
if(line[0]=="PING"):
    s.send("PONG %s\r\n" % line[1])
```

And `line` would be a single string of a single line. So accessing `[0]`, the first *character*, will never equal to a string of four characters.

---

So, to solve this, you should clean up your message parsing. You should always append new read text to the same buffer. And when you handle a line, just get a single (first) line from that buffer and handle that. And really handle each line separately. Something like this:

```
buffer = ''
while True:
    buffer += s.recv(1024)

    # are there completed lines we can parse?
    if '\n' in buffer:
        # only split once, keep the rest of the buffer
        line, buffer = buffer.split('\n', 1)

        # handle line
        if line.startswith('PING'):
            s.send('PONG {}\n'.format(line[5:]))
        elif line.startswith('PRIVMSG'):
            # this is an actual message; parse it, and handle the message
            pass
```

Finally, from my own experience, you really shouldn’t throw out the connection commands like that (the `NICK`, `USER` and `JOIN` ones). Many servers will ignore them when you send them too early. Instead wait for appropriate responses first, e.g. a welcome message, that will tell you that the server is ready for your messages.

Comment: Although some servers will send messages before the user registers with `NICK` and `USER`, many servers do not. You should send `NICK` and `USER` immediately, and wait for numeric `001` before sending any other commands.

Answer (score 0):

You do:

```
text=s.recv(2040)
```

and then shortly thereafter:

```
readbuffer=readbuffer+s.recv(1024)
```

the first call to s.recv() will read the odd-numbered messages while the second call to s.recv() will read the even numbered messages. That's why you only see half the messages. Except when handling messages larger than the read buffer, don't call s.recv() more than once per loop.